# Validation Method in Domain Class

Tags: grails

I inherited an app from a consultant, and am trying to follow the code that finds a user from the database via two parameters - Providier and Identifier.

From what I gather, there is a controller method, which in turn calls a service method, and that service method calls what appears to be a validator in the domain class called **Login**.

I feel like I have reached a dead-end here.  Where would I expect to find the actual code for **Login.findByProviderAndIdentifier()**?

```
class Login {
  String id
  String identifier
  String password
  boolean generated = false
  Provider provider
    Date lastUpdated
    Date dateCreated
    Boolean isActive = true

    static constraints = {
        identifier(blank:false,
                   validator: {val, obj, errs ->
                       if (val && obj.provider && !obj.generated) {
                           def dbLogin = Login.findByProviderAndIdentifier(obj.provider, val)
                           if (dbLogin && dbLogin.id != obj.id) {
                               errs.rejectValue("identifier", "unique", [obj.provider.name, obj.identifier] as Object[], "Identifier ${obj.identifier} already exists for provider ${obj.provider.name}")
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is a dynamic finder. The "actual code" for it is generated on the fly by GORM. The way [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) describes it is:

> GORM supports the concept of dynamic finders. A dynamic finder looks
>   like a static method invocation, but the methods themselves don't
>   actually exist in any form at the code level.
>
> Instead, a method is auto-magically generated using code synthesis at
>   runtime, based on the properties of a given class.

So in this case GORM creates a select statement with a where clause that takes a provider id and the identifier value that's being validated.

If you want to see the generated query you can turn on Hibernate SQL logging, or set up [log4jdbc](http://log4jdbc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Just read the link you provided.  Very enlightening.  Will accept as soon as I am allowed.